# Convergence in perturbative renormalization

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, statistical-physics

Consider the following:
$$G(\phi,W) = -\log \int d\mu_{C}(\psi)e^{-W(\phi+\psi)} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
which is very common in QFT. Here $d\mu_{C}$ is a Gaussian measure with covariance $C$. I want to understand the role of different expansions in the study of $G$. If you want, consider this a fermionic theory so there is no problem with the logarithm.

As far as I know, even with cutoffs one has to prove that $G$ is well-defined provided $W$ is. This is done by proving that $\|G(W)\| <+\infty$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is defined in some sense. In fermionic theories this is often done with respect to a norm parameter $h > 0$:
$$\|G(W)\|_{h} = \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}h^{2m}\int_{x_{1},...,x_{m}}|G_{m}^{(j)}(0,x_{2},...,x_{m})| \tag{2}\label{2}$$

One possible way to proceed is to formally Taylor expand $G$:
$$G(W) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}\frac{\partial^{m}G(t_{1}W_{1}+\cdots +t_{m}W_{m})}{\partial t_{1}\cdots \partial t_{m}}\bigg{|}_{t_{1} = \cdots =t_{m} = 0}$$
Then, one tries to prove that this series converges absolutely, in such a way that it exists and is analytic in $W$.

However, there are other alternative formulas. For example, there is the famous Brydges-Kennedy formula. Of course, one can use it to prove that $\|G(W)\|$ converges in this case, but since it is not an expansion in powers of $W$, it does not seem a way to prove $G(W)$ is analytic in $W$.

I believe it is important to prove that $G(W)$ is analytic in $W$ to use the renormalization group, and this makes me confused about the role played by, say, Brydges-Kennedy tree formula or whetever other formula that is not a Taylor expansion. Do we first prove the existence of $G$ by whatever formula we want, and then expand in Taylor to get analyticity? But then, isn't it twice the work?

I am a little confused about it and I would be glad if someone could help me understand it. Do we need analyticity, or is it enough to prove bounds for $\|G(W)\|$? Does Brydges-Kennedy tree formula (or any other expansion) provide analyticity? Do we need Taylor expansions?